# Dealing with R type of variables when doing multiple imputation with the mi package

Tags: r, missing-data, data-imputation

[Volume 45](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v45) of the *Journal of Statistical Software* contains articles about packages that deal with imputation of missing data, one of which is the [mi](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mi/index.html) package. In the PDF article regarding that package there is an example about a study of HIV-positive people. Below I copy the R commands and the output.

```
library(mi)
data(CHAIN)
info <- mi.info(CHAIN)
info
```

And here is the output:

```
           names    include order  number.mis   all.mis       type            collinear

1        h39b.W1     Yes     1         179       No         nonnegative             No
2         age.W1     Yes     2         24        No      positive-continuous        No
3         c28.W1     Yes     3         38        No      positive-continuous        No
4         pcs.W1     Yes     4         24        No      positive-continuous        No
5       mcs37.W1     Yes     5         24        No            binary               No
6         b05.W1     Yes     6         63        No      ordered-categorical        No
7 haartadhere.W1     Yes     7         24        No      ordered-categorical        No
```

where we see the type of each variable. The next step is how these variables are transformed:

```
CHAIN.new <- mi.preprocess(CHAIN)
attr(CHAIN.new, "mi.info")
```

where the output is:

```
          names include order number.mis all.mis           type          collinear
1 h39b.W1.mi.log     Yes     1        367      No      log-continuous        No
2  age.W1.mi.log     Yes     2         24      No      log-continuous        No
3  c28.W1.mi.log     Yes     3         38      No      log-continuous        No
4  pcs.W1.mi.log     Yes     4         24      No      log-continuous        No
5       mcs37.W1     Yes     5         24      No              binary        No
6         b05.W1     Yes     6         63      No ordered-categorical        No
7 haartadhere.W1     Yes     7         24      No ordered-categorical        No
8 h39b.W1.mi.ind     Yes     8        179      No              binary        No
```

Now here is my question, in the PDF article (p.17) I read

> For example, you can change the type of h39b.W1 from nonnegative to continuous as: (...)

and the R command is

```
info.upd <- update(info, "type", list("h39b.W1"="continuous"))
info.upd
```

and the new info table is

```
           names include order number.mis all.mis                type collinear
1        h39b.W1     Yes     1        179      No          continuous        No
2         age.W1     Yes     2         24      No positive-continuous        No
3         c28.W1     Yes     3         38      No positive-continuous        No
4         pcs.W1     Yes     4         24      No positive-continuous        No
5       mcs37.W1     Yes     5         24      No              binary        No
6         b05.W1     Yes     6         63      No ordered-categorical        No
7 haartadhere.W1     Yes     7         24      No ordered-categorical        No
```

where we can see that `h39b.W1` has changed fron nonnegative to continuous. My problem is that I can't find the appropriate `mi.preprocess` command so that the program will understand that `h39b.w1` is not nonnegative and consequently it shouldn't be transformed.